# Howto "Enable feature simplification for newly added layers" with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, rendering

Having some performance issues getting huge vector layers to be drawn the first time under heavy system load, I am interested to test what is called in QGIS application "Enable feature simplification by default for newly added layers" from the QGIS settings menu.

What is the PyQGIS equivalent to the QGIS setting? Is there a setting for individual layers only?

I am required to use PyQGIS 2.8 on Linux.